# Browsershot TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, pdf, puppeteer, node-modules, browsershot

I want to generate pdf using puppeteer in laravel 8. It is generating pdf, if i set timeout, but shows error instead to redirecting to generated pdf. And if i don't set timeout, then pdf does not generate and showing the error. Below is my code -

```
$content = view('/index')->render();

Browsershot::html($content)
    ->setNodeBinary('/usr/bin/node')
    ->setNpmBinary('/usr/bin/npm')
    ->setNodeModulePath(base_path('node_modules/'))
    ->format('A3')
    ->savePdf('sample.pdf');

return Redirect::to('sample.pdf');
```

When i run the code, this error is showing -

```
Error Output:\n================\nTimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded\n    at LifecycleWatcher._LifecycleWatcher_createTimeoutPromise
```

Please help me out where i am wrong.

Comment: https://github.com/statikbe/laravel-puppeteer-pdf-converter#usage